# Postgres query timestamp by datepart only

Tags: postgresql, date, query-performance

I'm using this to try and get all events with a timestamp of today

```
SELECT systemuserid,ondate from auditlog 
WHERE ondate::date = NOW()::date
```

Performance seems really bad, over 2 minutes. I have a index on ondate.

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a range condition:

```
select *
from auditlog
where ondate >= current_date
  and ondate < current_date + 1;
```

`current_date` will be converted to a timestamp at midnight, so `ondate => current_date` will include everything from "today".

And the condition `ondate < current_date + 1` will exclude rows with a timestamp of tomorrow (midnight) or later.

Comment: Thanks, that does it in under a second!